# Node Js mysql multiple query issues

Tags: mysql, node.js, io, node-mysql, node.io

I am working on IO project and I am having issue, when I am trying to do multiple mysql queries under one funtionality.

When match win Calculations are happening Mysql selects just does not happen and error is being thrown that winner object is missing.

I have tried to resolve this in multiple ways:
1) When I tried to nest second select query under first select query result functionality - It did throw Mysql error

> Error: Cannot enqueue Quit after invoking quit.

2) I tried to remove all conenction.end() and leave just one at the end of calcualtion functionality. -> It resulted in

> Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit.

*Does anyone have any tips how to adjust code in manner, where I can have queries nested one after another, I believe that I have missed some minor detail.*

```
if(data.gameStatus == 'calculation'){
        //winner data
        mysqlConnect();
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM users where username = "'+data.winnerData.username+'"', function(err, result){
            if(err){
                getDateTimeNow();
                console.log(err);
                console.log(datetime+' Error occured while calculating game score for'+ data.winnerData.username);
                console.log('============================================================');
            }
            else{
                winner = result;
            }
        });
        //loser data
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM users where username = "'+data.winnerData.username+'"', function(err, result){
            if(err){
                getDateTimeNow();
                console.log(err);
                console.log(datetime+' Error occured while calculating game score for'+ data.loserData.username);
                console.log('============================================================');
            }
            else{
                loser = result;
            }
        });
        // rank calculations
        var gameTime = data.gameTime;

        var winnerPointsBefore = winner[0].points;
        var winnerRank = winner[0].rank;
        var winnerDefuses = data.winnerData.minesDefused;
        var winnerFlags = data.winnerData.fieldsFlagged;
        var winnerId = winner[0].id;
        var winnerUsername = winner[0].username;
        var winnerGamesWon = winner[0].games_won;
        var winnerGamesLost = winner[0].games_lost;
        var winnerCoins = winner[0].coins;

        var timeBonus = 0;
        var rankPointAfterModifier = 0;

        var loserRank = loser[0].rank;
        var loserPointsBefore = loser[0].points;
        var loserDefuses = data.losetData.minesDefused;
        var loserFlags = data.loserData.fieldsFlagged;
        var loserId = loser[0].id;
        var loserUsername = loser[0].username;
        var loserGamesWon = loser[0].games_won;
        var loserGamesLost = loser[0].games_lost;
        var loserCoins = loser[0].coins;

        if(winnerPointsBefore - loserPointsAfter > 700){
            //If pro is facing noob which is 1.5 rank bellow he cannot gain more or less than 15 point
            rankPointAfterModifier = 15;
        }else{
            if(winnerDefuses == 10 && winnerFlags >= winnerDefuses){
                //Game won by defusing all mines -> time bonus calculations depending on rank
                timeBonus = 70 - 10*winnerRank - gameTime;
                if(loserFlags > loserDefuses){
                    loserFalseFlags = loserFlags - loserDefuses;
                    opponentPointReduction = 5 * (loserDefuses - loserFalseFlags);
                    if(opponentPointReduction < 0) {
                        opponentPointReduction = 0;
                    }
                }else{
                    opponentPointReduction = 5 * loserDefuses;
                }
            pointsGained = (winnerDefuses * 5) - opponentPointReduction + timeBonus;
            }else{
                //Game won by opponent exploding(retard lose scenario)
                if(loserFlags > loserDefuses){
                    loserFalseFlags = loserFlags - loserDefuses;
                    opponentPointReduction = 5 * (loserDefuses - loserFalseFlags);
                    if(opponentPointReduction < 0) {
                        opponentPointReduction = 0;
                    }
                }else{
                    opponentPointReduction = 5 * loserDefuses;
                }
                pointsGained = 5 * (winnerDefuses * (winnerFlags / winnerDefuses)) - opponentPointReduction;
            }
            if(winnerRank != loserRank){
                rankPointAfterModifier = -0.2 * (winnerRank-loserRank) * pointsGained;
            }
            else{
                rankPointAfterModifier = pointsGained;
            }
        }
        winnerCoinsEarned = Math.floor(rankPointAfterModifier / 2);
        loserCoinsEarned = Math.floor(rankPointAfterModifier / 5);  
        winnerPointsAfter = winnerPointsBefore + rankPointAfterModifier;
        loserPointsAfter = loserPointsBefore - rankPointAfterModifier;
        // Register game data in sql
        var gameLog = {
            winner_id: winnerId,
            loser_id: loserId,
            winner_name: winnerUsername,
            loser_name: loserUsername,
            winner_defuses: winnerDefuses,
            winner_flagged: winnerFlags,
            loser_defuses: loserDefuses,
            loser_flagged: loserFlags,
            game_time: gameTime,
            rank_exchanged: rankPointAfterModifier,
            winner_coins_gain: winnerCoinsEarned,
            loser_coins_gain: loserCoinsEarned
        }
            connection.query('INSERT INTO gamelog SET ?', gameLog, function(err, result){
                if(err){
                    getDateTimeNow();
                    console.log(err);
                    console.log(datetime+' Error occured while Registering game Log  1337');
                    console.log('============================================================');
                }
                getDateTimeNow();
                console.log(datetime+  "Game result has been registered: "+result.insertId);
                console.log('============================================================');
            });
        //Register data to game history for player
            //winner
            winnerGamesWon++;
            winnerRankNow = 1;
            if(winnerPointsAfter >= 1500){
                winnerRankNow = 2;
            }
            if(winnerPointsAfter >= 1800){
                winnerRankNow = 3;
            }
            if(winnerPointsAfter >= 2100){
                winnerRankNow = 4;
            }
            if(winnerPointsAfter >= 2500){
                winnerRankNow = 5;
            }
            totalWinnerCoins = winnerCoins + winnerCoinsEarned;
            connection.query('UPDATE users SET  games_won = '+winnerGamesWon+', coins = '+totalWinnerCoins+', points ='+winnerPointsAfter+',rank = '+winnerRankNow+' WHERE id = '+winnerId, function(err, result){
                if(err){
                    getDateTimeNow();
                    console.log(err);
                    console.log(datetime+' Error occured while Updating winner rank points  1336');
                    console.log('============================================================');
                }
                getDateTimeNow();
                console.log(datetime+  "Rank point has been updated for: "+ winnerUsername);
                console.log('============================================================');
            });
            //winner
            loserGamesLost++;
            loserRankNow = 1;
            if(loserPointsAfter >= 1500){
                loserRankNow = 2;
            }
            if(loserPointsAfter >= 1800){
                loserRankNow = 3;
            }
            if(loserPointsAfter >= 2100){
                loserRankNow = 4;
            }
            if(loserPointsAfter >= 2500){
                loserRankNow = 5;
            }
            totalLoserCoins = loserCoins + loserCoinsEarned;
            connection.query('UPDATE users SET  games_lost = '+loserGamesLost+', coins= '+totalLoserCoins+', points ='+loserPointsAfter+',rank = '+loserRankNow+' WHERE id = '+loserId, function(err, result){
                if(err){
                    getDateTimeNow();
                    console.log(err);
                    console.log(datetime+' Error occured while Updating winner rank points  1336');
                    console.log('============================================================');
                }
                getDateTimeNow();
                console.log(datetime+  "Rank point has been updated for: "+ winnerUsername);
                console.log('============================================================');
            });
        returnData = {
            loser : {
                username: loserUsername,
                rankPointsBefore: loserPointsBefore,
                rankPointsAfter: loserPointsAfter,
                loserCoinsEarned: loserCoinsEarned
            },
            winner : {
                username: winnerUsername,
                rankPointsBefore: winnerPointsBefore,
                rankPointsAfter: winnerPointsAfter,
                winnerCoinsEarned: winnerCoinsEarned
            },
            totalRankPoints: winnerPointsBefore + loserPointsBefore 
        }
    }
```

Comment: *"I believe that I have missed some minor detail."*  It's actually a **major** detail.  You're treating `connection.query()` as if it were synchronous.  You also need to stop building queries using string concatenation, but that is "only" causing security vulnerabilities that are unrelated to the errors you see.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot -> I will add input escapes after I am done with core.
In this context how then I should use connection query ?

I need to get loser and winner data and only then do all the calculations, which contain Insert and update queries. Does Select query also closes connection ? Because right now pattern of this issue does not make sense to me at all

Comment: I don't know how to begin explaining the issue, but `connection.query()` does not block.  Execution proceeds immediately to the next statement, with the inner callback happening later.  You can't use non-blocking tools to write blocking code.